# Correct way to implement a Search Query MySql

Tags: php, mysql, search

I'm working on an app that connects to an PHP server to retrieve some data. I have a bunch of articles which have a title like "how to bath your dog". I need to implement a search function (server side) which user can type certain words and searchs for the articles that could match the query.

This is my actual implementation:

```
$texto_buscar = $_POST['texto_buscar'];
                         $sql = "SELECT  `id_seccion`,`id_articulo`,`upvotes`, `downvotes`, `titulo_articulo`,`categorias_articulos` 
                         FROM `indice_articulos`
                         WHERE `titulo_articulo` like :texto_buscar
                         ORDER BY `id_articulo` ASC";

                         $stmt0 = $pdo->prepare($sql);
                         $stmt0->bindvalue(':texto_buscar','%'.$texto_buscar.'%');
                         $stmt0->execute();
```

I saw its not optimal because if the user types a very long string, the LIKE part fails.
I've been googling around and didn't find any sort of standard, but I think it's a common need so there should be an Standard. That's what i'm looking for.

Please point me at the right direction.

Comment: why does the like part fail if user types a lot? o.o

Comment: I put fail because it would be useless in case the query sentence have to match the title almost exactly, so the functionality wouldn't be as intended.

Comment: What do you mean by "the LIKE part fails"? Can you provide a reproducable example of that behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use full text search, which is definitely optimized.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE MATCH(titulo_articulo )
AGAINST('search terms' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Edit: Make sure you have created index on the column that you are applying full search on.

Comment: Hi Danyal, It worked!
But to consider this answer as a complete one. I Suggest you edit and put that first you have to create an index to achieve this.

Comment: you mean creating index on the `titulo_articulo` column right?

Comment: Yes. The query wouldn't work without it.

Comment: added it, that's the pre-req for full text search if I am not wrong.